# Split character vector at math comparisons signs in R

Tags: r, regex

I would like to split expression with mathematical comparisons, e.g.

```
unlist(strsplit("var<3", "(?=[=<>])", perl = TRUE))
unlist(strsplit("var==5", "(?=[=<>])", perl = TRUE))
unlist(strsplit("var>2", "(?=[=<>])", perl = TRUE))
```

The results are:

```
[1] "var" "<"   "3"  
[1] "var" "="   "="   "5"  
[1] "var" ">"   "2"
```

For the 2nd example above, I would like to get `[1] "var" "=="   "5"`, so the two `=` should be returned as a single element. How do I need to change my regular expression to achieve this? (I already tried grouping and quantifiers for "==", but nothing worked - regular expressions are not my friends...)

Comment: Do you only want to limit to `>`, `<` and `==`?

Comment: @Wiktor, yes, I only want to limit the splits at >, < and ==. Maybe also !=.

Comment: Btw, you can capture each part using `sub("(.*?)([=<>].)(.*)", "\\2", "var==55", perl = TRUE)` or something similar. You can also use it for splitting `strsplit(sub("(.*?)([=<>].)(.*)", "\\1 \\2 \\3", "var==55", perl = TRUE), " ")` but Wiktors solution is better probably

Comment: If ocnvenient for your use case, there is, always, the parsing option: `lapply(unlist(lapply(c("var<3", "var==5", "var>2"), function(e) parse(text = e))), sapply, deparse)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, your above example with _strplit_ produces `[1] "var" ">5"  "5"` when I use `"var>55"` as x in sub().

Comment: Yeah, you are right, maybe `(.*?)([=<>].*?)(\\d.*)` is a bit better

Comment: @alexis_laz yes, that would be working for my case, too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use a PCRE regex to *match* the substrings you need:

```
==|[<>]|(?:(?!==)[^<>])+
```

To also support `!=`, modify it as

```
[!=]=|[<>]|(?:(?![=!]=)[^<>])+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a397fe/2).

**Details**:

- `==` - 2 `=` signs
- `|` - or
- `[<>]` - a `<` or `>`
- `|` - or
- `(?:(?!==)[^<>])+` - 1 or more chars other than `<` and `>` (`[^<>]`) that do not start a `==` char sequence (a *tempered greedy token*).

**NOTE**: This is easily expandable by adding more alternatives and adjusting the tempered greedy token.

[R test](https://ideone.com/VpOQew):

```
> text <- "Text1==text2<text3><More here"
> res <- regmatches(text, gregexpr("==|[<>]|(?:(?!==)[^<>])+", text, perl=TRUE))
> res
[[1]]
[1] "Text1"     "=="        "text2"     "<"         "text3"     ">"        
[7] "<"         "More here"
```

Comment: I had go with `([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)([^a-zA-Z0-9_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)` as regex as operators chars should not appear in any side of them.

Comment: @Tensibai: do you mean you had to check if there are word chars on both sides of those operators? You could just use [`"\\b(?:[!=]=|[<>])\\b"`](https://regex101.com/r/0khTUq/1)

Comment: For regmatches to return 3 captures groups I think it's better to specify them, using perl like for \w would be better also, but I feel it's easier to understand like this. I.e:  `regmatches(tests,regexec("([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)([^a-zA-Z0-9_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)",tests))` where tests is a vector would give the initial with each part in it's own capture group. (That's just an alternative)

Comment: I think I understand now why you suggest this: OP sample input strings are short 2 part operator-separated strings. In this case, I generalized the problem to find any known operators and the rest.

Comment: Ho, yes, I kept it simple :)

Answer (score 6):

Expanding from my idea in comments, just for the formatting:

```
tests=c("var==5","var<3","var.name>5")
regmatches(tests,regexec("([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)(\\W+)([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)",tests))
```

`\w` is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `\W` it's opposite `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`, I expanded it after comment to include . in the character class, and as R doesn't support \w in character class in base regex (need to use perl=TRUE).

So the regex search for a least 1 of \w and ., then a least 1 not in \w (to match operators) and then a least 1 of \w and dot.

Each step is captured, and this give:

```
[[1]]
[1] "var==5" "var"    "=="     "5"     

[[2]]
[1] "var<3" "var"   "<"     "3"    

[[3]]
[1] "var.name>5" "var.name"   ">"          "5"
```

you may add `*` between each capture group if your entries could have space around the operator, if not the operator capture will get them.

Comment: nice one (I'll take it you don't mind I use you to simplify my regex) ;-p

Comment: Thanks, nice und short solution - however, this one does not work with variable names with dots, e.g. `regmatches("var.name==5",regexec("(\\w+)(\\W+)(\\w+)","var.name==5"))`. I tried something like `regmatches("var.name==5",regexec("(\\w|[.]+)(\\W+)(\\w+)","var.name==5"))`, but that one eats the "==" part of the character vector.

Comment: @Daniel corrected, just use a character class to add `.` to the allowed chars

Comment: @Daniel This: `(\\w|[.]+)` mean any char from \w once OR a dot at least one time, maybe `(\\w|[.])`+ may have worked better (for matching, the capture would be awfull) but with backtracking you'll probably have a problem

Answer (score 5):

Using words' boundaries (`\\b`) and specifying 2 possibilities for the lookaround:

```
unlist(strsplit("var==5", "(?=(\\b[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(\\b[a-zA-Z0-9]\\b))", perl = TRUE))
[1] "var" "=="  "5" 

unlist(strsplit("var<3", "(?=(\\b[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(\\b[a-zA-Z0-9]\\b))", perl = TRUE))
[1] "var" "<"   "3"
unlist(strsplit("var>2", "(?=(\\b[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(\\b[a-zA-Z0-9]\\b))", perl = TRUE))
[1] "var" ">"   "2"
```

*Explanation:*

Split at the end of the "word" and, after, there is either a non-alphanumeric character `\\b[^a-zA-Z0-9]` or it is the end of the "word" and, after, there is an alphanumeric character.

**EDIT:**

Actually the above code would have unexpected results if the number at the end is 10 or more.
Another option is to use `lookbehind` and split when, before, there is either a non alphanum character followed by a word edge, or an alphanum character followed by a word edge:

```
strsplit("var<20", "(?<=(([^a-zA-Z0-9]\\b)|([a-zA-Z0-9]\\b)))", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "var" "<"   "20"
strsplit("var==20", "(?<=(([^a-zA-Z0-9]\\b)|([a-zA-Z0-9]\\b)))", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "var" "=="  "20"
strsplit("var!=5", "(?<=(([^a-zA-Z0-9]\\b)|([a-zA-Z0-9]\\b)))", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "var" "!="  "5"
```

**EDIT2:**

Totally stealing @Tensibai way to define alphanum(+underscore)/non alphanum characters, the above `regex` can be simplify to: `"(?<=((\\W\\b)|(\\w\\b)))"`